# Click on table row if text is found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use this Java code with Selenium to select table row based on found text:

```
WebElement tableContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']"));

        List<WebElement> list = tableContainer.findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));

        // check for list elements and print all found elements
        if(!list.isEmpty())
        {
            for (WebElement element : list)
            {
                System.out.println("Found inner WebElement " + element.getText());
            }
        }

        // iterate sub-elements
        for ( WebElement element : list )
        {
            System.out.println("Searching for " + element.getText());

            if(element.getText().equals(valueToSelect))
            {
                element.click();
                break;  // We need to put break because the loop will continue and we will get exception
            }
        }
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/ANMqY01y

For some reason table text is not clicked. I don't have exception. Any idea why it's not working properly?

Comment: What is the size of list?

Comment: Can you possible edit down your HTML so it only shows the element in question and its ancestors? I cannot make heads or tails of it as is,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See there are 2 divs with `//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']` with this xpath.

first div does not have anything, while second div has child divs.

I would suggest you to use :

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']//div"));
```

Remove this line from your code :

```
WebElement tableContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!